# Cannot solve Error: Invalid Chai property: revertedWith

Tags: ethers.js, javascript, hardhat, chai

I am trying to run a test on my contract using hardhat and chai. But I am running into this error.
I have tried install ethereum-waffle. But it did not solve the problem. I also added ethereum-waffle using require to my hardhat config but that gave this error-

```
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/utils' is not defined by "exports" in /home/samarth/web3/hardhat-fundme/node_modules/ethers/package.json
    at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
    at throwExportsNotFound (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:332:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:565:3)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:450:36)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:490:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/samarth/web3/hardhat-fundme/node_modules/@ethereum-waffle/provider/src/CallHistory.ts:2:1) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Here is my FundMe.test file-

```
const { deployments, ethers, getNamedAccounts } = require("hardhat")
const { assert, expect } = require("chai")
describe("FundMe", async function () {
    let fundMe
    let deployer
    let mockV3Aggregator
    beforeEach(async function () {
        // const accounts = await ethers.getSigners()
        // const accountZero = accounts[0]
        deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer
        await deployments.fixture(["all"])
        fundMe = await ethers.getContract("FundMe", deployer)
        mockV3Aggregator = await ethers.getContract(
            "MockV3Aggregator",
            deployer
        )
    })
    describe("constructor", async function () {
        it("sets the aggregator addresses correctly", async function () {
            const response = await fundMe.gePriceFeed()
            assert.equal(response, await mockV3Aggregator.getAddress())
        })
    })

    describe("fund", async function () {
        it("Fails if you dont send enough ETH", async function () {
            await expect(fundMe.fund()).to.be.revertedWith(
                "You need to spend more"
            )
        })
    })
})
```

and my hardhat config file-

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle")
require("hardhat-gas-reporter")
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan")
require("dotenv").config()
require("solidity-coverage")
require("hardhat-deploy")
// You need to export an object to set up your config
// Go to https://hardhat.org/config/ to learn more
/**
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 */

const COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY = process.env.COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY || ""
const SEPOLIA_RPC_URL =
    process.env.SEPOLIA_RPC_URL ||
    "https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/YOUR-API-KEY"
const PRIVATE_KEY =
    process.env.PRIVATE_KEY ||
    "0x11ee3108a03081fe260ecdc106554d09d9d1209bcafd46942b10e02943effc4a"
const ETHERSCAN_API_KEY = process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY || ""

module.exports = {
    defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
    networks: {
        hardhat: {
            chainId: 31337,
            // gasPrice: 130000000000,
        },
        sepolia: {
            url: SEPOLIA_RPC_URL,
            accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
            chainId: 11155111,
            blockConfirmations: 6,
        },
    },
    solidity: {
        compilers: [
            {
                version: "0.8.7",
            },
            {
                version: "0.6.6",
            },
        ],
    },
    etherscan: {
        apiKey: ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
        // customChains: [], // uncomment this line if you are getting a TypeError: customChains is not iterable
    },
    gasReporter: {
        enabled: true,
        currency: "USD",
        outputFile: "gas-report.txt",
        noColors: true,
        // coinmarketcap: COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY,
    },
    namedAccounts: {
        deployer: {
            default: 0, // here this will by default take the first account as deployer
            1: 0, // similarly on mainnet it will take the first account as deployer. Note though that depending on how hardhat network are configured, the account 0 on one network can be different than on another
        },
    },
    mocha: {
        timeout: 500000,
    },
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/145473/error-err-package-path-not-exported-package-subpath-lib-utils-is-not-defi

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error \[ERR\_PACKAGE\_PATH\_NOT\_EXPORTED\]: Package subpath './lib/utils' is not defined by "exports" in node\_modules\ethers\package.json](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/145473/error-err-package-path-not-exported-package-subpath-lib-utils-is-not-defi)